# why datetimepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i am using the following code for datetimepicker but i am unable to understand why it is not working. I mean in the input box nothing is shown. Please help me ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/i18n/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-i18n.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({  
      showSecond: true,
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 2,
      stepMinute: 10,
      stepSecond: 10

     });  

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="datepicker" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're loading the i18n language library for the datetimepicker, not the datetimepicker plugin itself.

Comment: so what should i do. Please help me ??

Comment: You need to include the right .js file - the one that contains the plugin.

Comment: i mean i am not getting it. Please be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the following too:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

^ Here is the plugin js & css.

And here you will find all the scripts/css files that you need: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon